Typescript files not running due to strict mode
here is the code
mkdir generate-keypair
cd generate-keypair
npm init -y
npm install typescript @solana/web3.js esrun @solana-developers/helpers

and  make a new file called generate-keypair.ts
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";
const keypair = Keypair.generate();
console.log(`✅ Generated keypair!`)

but if I am running npx esrun generate-keypair.ts ,it's showing error like below
SyntaxError: \8 and \9 are not allowed in strict mode.
at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:167:18)
at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:285:14)
at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:291:30)
at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:21) 

kindly help how to deal with this strict mode

what's does your environment look like and what are the package versions you installed?

i installed only npm packages for now though I have ts node and other stuffs installed
